# Calculating percentage scores across observations

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataset where a certain number of variables constitute a 100 percent of the observation e.g,

```
        date  x y  z something
1 1998-01-01 12 2  1         a
2 1998-02-01 23 4 90         b
3 1998-03-01 55 6 23         c
```

combined `x`, `y`, `z` variables are a 100% of each observation (i.e., for `obs1` `x+y+z = 15 = 100%`; for `obs2` `x+y+z = 117 = 100%`; and for `obs3` `x+y+z = 84 = 100%`.

I want to calculate the values as percentage scores for each observation, so that the dataset would look like this:

```
        date     x     y     z something
1 1998-01-01 80.00  13.3  6.67         a
2 1998-02-01 19.66  3.42 76.92         b
3 1998-03-01 65.47  7.14 27.38         c
```

where `x`, `y`, and `z` variables represent proportion.
I am having a hard time figuring out how to do it int R. Thanks.

Dput:

```
structure(list(date = structure(c(10227, 10258, 10286), class = "Date"), 
x = c(12, 23, 55), y = c(2, 4, 6), z = c(1, 90, 23), something = c("a", 
"b", "c")), .Names = c("date", "x", "y", "z", "something"
), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
df <- mutate(df, total = x+y+z, p.x = 100*x/total, p.y = 100*y/total, p.z = 100*z/total)

        date  x y  z something total      p.x       p.y       p.z
1 1998-01-01 12 2  1         a    15 80.00000 13.333333  6.666667
2 1998-02-01 23 4 90         b   117 19.65812  3.418803 76.923077
3 1998-03-01 55 6 23         c    84 65.47619  7.142857 27.380952
```

Comment: `dplyr` has a `mutate_each` function just FYI.

Comment: Didn't know about that. Tried to update my answer, but could't do it, without generating `total` first, and then using `mutate_each(df, funs(100 * . / total), x,y,z)`

Answer (score 3):

Or just a simple and efficient base R solution

```
cols <- 2:4 # It is better to specify the actual column names instead of the locaions
df[cols] <- df[cols] / rowSums(df[cols]) * 100
df
#         date        x         y         z something
# 1 1998-01-01 80.00000 13.333333  6.666667         a
# 2 1998-02-01 19.65812  3.418803 76.923077         b
# 3 1998-03-01 65.47619  7.142857 27.380952         c
```